# How can I automate two-stage code generation in MSBuild?

Tags: c++, msbuild, msbuild-task

I would like to automate building and running a code generator that outputs a DLL in the following two steps:

1. The user writes regular classes in C++ and compiles them with a library-supplied `main.cpp` (sort of like how the Catch unit testing library works). The library's install path contains that `main.cpp` and I would prefer if users did not have to reference it directly (noisy).
2. The user then runs the resulting executable several times, once per "configuration", each of which emits an `.obj`. Finally, these `.obj` files are linked together to form the final `.dll`.

At the command line, this might look like (roughly):

```bash
# this command might link to one set of dependencies
cl gen1.cpp gen2.cpp gen3.cpp %LIBROOT%\main.cpp /link [...] /out:generator.exe

# run the generator and get object files
generator.exe %CONFIG1% /out:config1.out
generator.exe %CONFIG2% /out:config2.out

# link the objects together with a potentially different set of dependencies
link config1.out config2.out [...] /DLL /out:project.dll
```

How can I automate this in MSBuild? Must I create a custom project type? Can I reuse some of (or most) of the existing C++ targets? Ideally, I would like to simply include a custom targets file, have the user specify necessary metadata in the properties, and let the build system figure out the rest.

Comment: Create a post build step for first project copying generator.exe into second project. Set up config files to depend on generator.exe triggering build actions in second project. Set up third project to depend upon .out files produced by second project.

Comment: Surely _three_ projects aren't necessary. If I have hundreds of these types of projects to work with, I would then have three hundred, mostly boilerplate.

Comment: Maybe I could run the build recursively using the [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-task?view=vs-2017)? On the second run, the targets file could drop all the `ClCompile` items and add `Obj` items for each of the generated files.